# Unable to identify specific data row field using datatable in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable

I am getting below issue in visual studio.

- Issue:

  'DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and no extension method 'Field' accepting a first argument of type 'DataRow' could be found

Visual Studio -- 2017

.NET Framework -- 4.6.1

**Sample Code:**

```
      int userid = 1000;
      DataTable dt = GetuserDetails(userid);
      string userName= dt.Rows[0]. Field<string>("USERNAME"); --Error at Field<string>
```

I added reference "System.Data" as well. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you reference it like this?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        d.Columns.Add("Foo", typeof(string));
        DataRow row = d.NewRow();       
        row["Foo"] = "Bar";
        d.Rows.Add(row);

        Console.WriteLine((string)d.Rows[0]["Foo"]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataRow.Field<T> extension requires a reference to **System.Data.DataSetExtensions**.  Adding that reference should fix your problem.